# How can I make a bottom-up mergesort function that mutates the input list?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, mergesort, mutability

I am trying to implement a bottom-up mergesort in Python along the lines of the second example on this Wikipedia page (said to be written in “C-like code”):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

I have created a script that works, but when I try to encapsulate it in a function, that function fails to mutate the input list. Mutating the input list **is** what I want it to do.

Does anybody know why my function BottomUpMergeSort cannot alter the input list? I am aware that nested while loops are not recommended, but the first script seems to work fine. Many thanks in advance.

My first script, which mutates list A:

```py
import random

A = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(A)

def Merge(a, b, start, mid, end):
    i = start
    j = mid
    for k in range(start, end):
        if i < mid and (j >= end or a[i] <= a[j]):
            b[k] = a[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            b[k] = a[j]
            j += 1

print(f'A: {A}')
# 'A: [3, 4, 5, 1, 8, 7, 2, 9, 0, 6]'

n = len(A)
B = A[:]
width = 1
while width < n:
    start = 0
    while start < n:
        mid = min(n, start + width)
        end = min(n, start + (2 * width))
        Merge(A, B, start, mid, end)
        start += 2 * width
    A = B[:]
    width *= 2

print(f'A: {A}')
# 'A: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'
```

My second script, which does not mutate list A:

```py
import random

A = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(A)

def Merge(a, b, start, mid, end):
    i = start
    j = mid
    for k in range(start, end):
        if i < mid and (j >= end or a[i] <= a[j]):
            b[k] = a[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            b[k] = a[j]
            j += 1

print(f'A: {A}')
# 'A: [1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 0, 2]'

def BottomUpMergeSort(a):
    n = len(a)
    b = a[:]
    width = 1
    while width < n:
        start = 0
        while start < n:
            mid = min(n, start + width)
            end = min(n, start + (2 * width))
            Merge(a, b, start, mid, end)
            start += 2 * width
        a = b[:]
        width *= 2

BottomUpMergeSort(A)

print(f'A: {A}')
# 'A: [1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 0, 2]'
```

As you can see, the first script changes A, while the second does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
    a = b[:]
```

By assigning something to `a` in `BottomUpMergeSort`, you make it a local variable to this function. So, the list you assign to this local `a` just gets discarded when you exit the function.

If you want your original list to get mutated, just mutate it. An easy way here would be to assign to a slice, like this:

```
    a[:] = b[:]
```

This way, all the values of the original `a` get replaced, but you don't create a new object.

Output of the modified code:

```
BottomUpMergeSort(A)
print(A)

# A: [8, 9, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 0]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```